# Change background image on user's choice

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image

Guys I want the user to change the background image of all the activities in my app on user selection.
I am able to change the background image of the `Activity` from where am changing the image
but if I try to change the image of other `Activity`, I get a `NullPointerException`! 
Yes, I have checked that the id of other activity's `Layout` ! 
this is the code.

```
public class setting extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    CheckBox cbS, theme1, theme2;
    RelativeLayout rel;
    OnClickListener checkBoxListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);

        cbS = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb);
        theme1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.theme1);
        theme2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.theme2);
        // cbW=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbWordPress);
        checkBoxListener = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cbS.isChecked()) {
                    // anything
                }

                if (theme2.isChecked()) {
                    RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel);
                    Resources res = getResources();
                    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.back_image1);
                    rel.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                    // findViewById(R.id.rel).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_image1);
                }

            }
        };

        cbS.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
        theme2.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
        // cbW.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this.. When you refer a layout file using `findViewById()`, the android system looks for this in your current `ContentView` only. (i.e the view which you have set using `setContentView()` for the current **activity**). So obvioulsy the sytem will not be able find the resource you are specifying and hence you will get the NullPointerExeption only.

You have to maintain the reference to the backgrounds separately and use it in your other Activity when you actually pass on there.

Comment: I would go with saving the id of the image you want on your screens in a global variable like [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and when loading activity set background to the id saved there.

Comment: Or extend the Application class and store your Global Variables there.   Here is an example http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/maintaining-global-application-state

Comment: actually i didn't define the class in the manifest file, which is a must ! now  i did ! and it worked ! this idea is ultra cool! ;) 
thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot access the UI components which are not yet instantiated. Use Intents to pass information across activities (user's choice, or some custom flags or Strings) and use this "extra" information in the launched activity to change the background accordingly.

Read more about intents in the documentation for better understanding and examples.