# How do I set the Background/ Layout of a class from a different class in Android

Tags: java, android, layout, sharedpreferences, setbackground

I am working with some code where I want to change the background image dynamically while referencing the shared preferences. An example of an activity I have is this:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle inputVariableToSendToSuperClass) {

        super.onCreate(inputVariableToSendToSuperClass);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Initialize();

        //Setting background
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String user_choice = prefs.getString("pref_background_choice","blue_glass");
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_splash_layout);
        ManagePreferences mp = new ManagePreferences();
        mp.setTheBackground(Splash.this, user_choice, layout);

        //More code after this...
    }
}
```

The ManagePreferences class looks like this:

```
public class ManagePreferences {

    //Empty Constructor
    public ManagePreferences(){
    }

    public void setTheBackground(Context context, String background_choice, LinearLayout layout){
        if (background_choice == "blue_glass"){
            layout.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_glass));
        } else if (background_choice == "blue_oil_painting")


             //etc... with more backgrounds
        }
}
```

The problem is, the code for setting the background is not working from a different class. I can get the code to work if I copy it into the Splash activity, but not if I reference the class and call the method; I would prefer to not clutter my code.

All I am trying to do is change the layout (setBackgroundDrawable) in the Splash Activity by making a call to this ManagePreferences class.

Thanks all!

Comment: I updated my answer. Did it help? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You doing it wrong. You shouldn't create `Activity` directly by using `new`.

2) You should open new Activity using `Intent` and set arguments to it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ManagePreferences.class);
intent.putExtra("user_choice", user_choice);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in `ManagePreferences` get it:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String user_choice = extras.getString("user_choice");
}
```

**UPD:** If you are using `ManagePreferences` just like utility class, make `setTheBackground` static:

```
public static void setTheBackground(Context context, String background_choice, LinearLayout layout){
        if (background_choice == "blue_glass"){
            layout.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_glass));
        } else if (background_choice == "blue_oil_painting")


             //etc... with more backgrounds
        }
        layout.requestLayout();
     }
```

and call it:

```
ManagePreferences.setTheBackground(this, user_choice, layout);
```

**UPD:** as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576668/change-background-image-on-users-choice), you cannot do this. When you refer a layout file using `findViewById()`, the android system looks for this in your current `ContentView` only. (i.e the view which you have set using `setContentView()` for the current activity).

Comment: You are definitely correct with regards to passing data via an intent, the problem is, I am not opening up the other class. The ManagePreferences activity is never opened up as a class. I am simply trying to use it so run through the 10 if statements I have to run to figure set the background image. I'm trying to figure out a way to get the layout.setBackgroundDrawable() to reference the class that initially called the method. Basically, have the ManagePreferences class actually set the layout for the class that is calling it

Comment: @Silmarilos i really don't understand why are you using Activity and never open it =/

Comment: I updated the question to show that the ManagePreferences class is not an activity. Does that help make it a little more clear? I am NOT trying to open an activity, I am trying to use the ManagePreferences class to change the layout of the splash class

Comment: @Silmarilos hm, try to make setTheBackground as static. And you will call it without creating instance of class. And after setting bg, try to call requestLayout() on layout

Comment: Tried but no luck :( Apparently, it's something that can't be done. Check out the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576668/change-background-image-on-users-choice . I greatly appreciate your help trying Suvitruf! Would you like to post a link to that and mention that we can't alter the UI components in an answer and I'll select it as the right answer? Thanks again!

Comment: @Silmarilos ok, did it )